# Audio recording software with tuner?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, audio-recording

I've used Mixcraft on Windows, and one great feature is that it can have a tuner display when recording. This helps me play in tune when playing my woodwind instruments (mainly Ocarina).

I am wondering if there is any audio recording software in Ubuntu which has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I hope one of these will be helpful for you:

#### [lingot](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lingot)

> Accurate and easy to use musical instrument tuner

#### [gtkguitune](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gtkguitune)

> Guitar and other instruments tuner